# Book Request: Taylor's Theorem for functions $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request, taylor-expansion

I'm looking for a resource (e.g. a book, website, or arxiv paper) that goes over the general case of Taylor's theorem, with a full proof and examples.  Do you guys know of any material that covers this.

Comment: Unless you're looking for something rather unusual (e.g. do you really mean $f:{\mathbb R}^n \rightarrow {\mathbb R}^m$ and not $f:{\mathbb R}^n \rightarrow {\mathbb R}),$ it seems to me that most any advanced calculus text would work. C. H. Edwards' [**Advanced Caclulus of Several Variables**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0486683362) has one of the nicest treatments that I know of.

Comment: Are you looking for something involving [jets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_%28mathematics%29)?  Or something more [analytic](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1927-029-01/S0002-9947-1927-1501382-X/S0002-9947-1927-1501382-X.pdf)?